# boolean algebra - build a OR gate having NAN and AND

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

I'm working on some assignment and got to build few gates starting with only NAND gate.
At this moment I have already following: `AND`, `NOT`, `NAND`.

To build `AND` and `NOT` wasn't too diffucult since it was quite obvious how to manipulate `NAND` to get expected results just by looking at its truth table. However I already had  feeling that I'm doing things not in the right way. Now I stuck on building `OR` gate since I'm not able to find any relationship when just looking in truth table.

I do not need just an answer rather explaination and methodology that I could apply in future when building other gates as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
a + b
```

rewrite to

```
~~(a + b)  // Invert twice
```

then use De Morgan's law (i.e. `~(X + Y) = ~X * ~Y` ) and rewrite to

```
~(~a * ~b)
```

Now you can use the NOT you already have on both a and b and then followed by a NAND

Like:

[image]

BTW - free hand drawing in paint ain't easy :-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and describing how you got solution, but for still it doesn't makes sense and I feel like don't get an idea why I need to rewrite `a + b` to `~~(a + b)` and from where you got this expression. Can you please explain it in little more details or give me a link to some resources? Thanks!

Comment: @deividaspetraitis - In boolean algebra it is always legal to invert twice as it doesn't change the result of the expression. It is often a "trick" you can try when rewriting Boolean expressions. I just wrote it as a step in the process of getting from `a + b` to `~(~a * ~b)` - like a math prove.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously ~X = X nand X. Now using De Morgan duality, we have

```
X or Y = ~(~X and ~Y) = (X nand X) nand (Y nand Y)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! Can you please explain why `X or Y = ~(~X and ~Y) ` ? It is from De Morgan Duality? Maybe you have link to some resources I could take a look, solution is quite clear to be but I still would be not able to find it by my self. Thanks.

Comment: @deividaspetraitis See [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws): `~(X or Y) = ~X and ~Y`. Now applying "not" to both sides gives the desired result.